# Mysql returns duplicate results with numbered key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, duplicates

I did a SELECT query on MySQL and get this as result.

[image]

The problem is how can I remove the 2nd duplicated results at for instance we use the 1st item in the list. "0":"1" is a duplicate for "id":"1" I would rather use "id" instead of "0" as the key later on the the app. How could I remove this to simplify the results. I do notice that the "0" means the 1st column as the successive columns does add up by 1.

Here's the $query I run.

```
SELECT id FROM clubsinformation WHERE :comparisonTime < updateTime
```

Comment: share the query, result, structure

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Why dont you just select `ID` instead of the whole data (*) where you just wanna get the id? `SELECT id FROM...`

Comment: the image shown at the top shows select id only. I've tried selecting ID only and the results is the first image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by most likely the fetching mode, you need to fetch it by associative indices only because right now you're including both associative and numeric index fetching:

No matter what DB API you got, `MySQLi` or `PDO`, just set it to associative.

So that it turn it doesn't include the numeric indices, only the column names as keys:

So this would roughly look like in code *(from looking at your query placeholders, it seems PDO, so I'll draft a PDO example)*:

```
$data = array(); // container
$query = 'SELECT * FROM clubsinformation WHERE :comparisonTime < updateTime';
$select = $db->prepare($query);
$select->bindValue(':comparisonTime', $comparisonTime);
$select->execute();

while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // associative
    $data[] = $row; // only includes column names
}

// then finally, encode
echo json_encode($data);

// OR SIMPLY
// $data = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // associative
// echo json_encode($data);
```

That fetching is by way of `PDO` API. If you're using `MySQLi` you can still use the basic idea.